# "no such column" in WHEN clause

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I am coding a database that takes in various personal details and stores it as a form of securing tenure.

I am trying to use the South African ID number that is entered into the database to populate the Gender column (The 7th number in the ID number indicates gender, 0-4 indicates a female and 5-9 indicates a male)

I have tried to use the SUBSTR function to isolate the 7th letter and this works, however, when I try to use it as part of the WHEN statement while writing the trigger that executes the populating of the gender column which occurs when a value is inserted into the ID Number column, I get an error.

The code is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Community_Register (ID_Number TEXT CHECK (length(ID_Number)=13))

CREATE TABLE Occupant (ID_Number TEXT, Birth_Date TEXT, Gender TEXT)

CREATE TRIGGER insert_details AFTER INSERT ON Community_Register
WHEN ((substr(ID_Number,7,1)) = '5')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Occupant (ID_Number, Birth_Date, Gender)
VALUES (NEW.ID_Number, substr(NEW.ID_Number,1,6), 'Male');
END;
```

I have used this trigger without the WHEN statement for populating the Birth_Date column and it worked successfully. The issue seems to be with the WHEN statement.

I am coding in the command line and it allows me to enter the trigger but when I try to insert values into the Community_Register table like this:

```
INSERT INTO Community_Register(ID_Number) VALUES ('9512235193083');
```

I get this error:

> no such column: ID_Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an UPDATE trigger, you must differentiate between the contents of the old and the new rows by using `OLD.` and `NEW.` prefixes.

In an INSERT trigger, there is no old row, but you still have to use `NEW.`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
WHEN substr(NEW.ID_Number, 7, 1) BETWEEN '5' AND '9'
BEGIN
...
```